# subtract days to a DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime, subtraction

In my PHP code, I've to subtract one day from a DateTime object.
When the date is in the same year, it runs, but when I try to subtract one day from the 1st day of the year, it doesn't run.

The code is the following:

```
$date = date_create('20180101');
    $edition_date = $date->format('Ymd');
    $edition=$date->format('Ymd').'piacenza';
    $img_url = false;
    $count = 0;
    do {
    ++$count;
    $url='http://www.url.it/url/webservice/getThumb.jsp?edition='.$edition.'&height=400&half=true';
    $img_url = @imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
    if (!$img_url) {
        $edition_date = $edition_date - 1;
        $edition = $edition_date.'piacenza';
    }
    } while (!$img_url && $count < 5);
```

In this case, the calculated date is 20180096 and it's uncorrect.

Can you help me , please?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$date = date_create('20180101');

$edition=$date->format('Ymd').'piacenza';
$img_url = false;
$count = 0;
do {
    ++$count;
    $url='http://www.url.it/url/webservice/getThumb.jsp?edition='.$edition.'&height=400&half=true';
    $img_url = @imagecreatefromjpeg($url);

    if (!$img_url) {
        $edition = $date->modify('-1 day')->format('Ymd').'piacenza';
    }
} while (!$img_url && $count < 5);
```